Surely there is an easier way to do this? HTML, CSS, JS
I'm creating some animated lines that run from one side of the page to the other, while they are doing this they change in size, there are currently 5 animated lines and I may add more, but i also want them all to move across the screen at different intervals, change size at different intervals and if possible at random, so the animation never truly repeats itself.
Currently I can only think to write a a really long block of code for each line and it wouldn't be at random I would have to set left and width so it seems random, but it would evidently just be a pre programmed sequence that would keep repeating itself.
Surely this can be done with less code in JS and actually at random be randomly generated?
Currently I have the below keyframes:
@keyframes slider {
    0%  {width: 75%; left: 10%;}
    5%  {width: 66%; left: 18%;}
    10% {width: 60%; left: 26%;}
    15% {width: 31%; left: 34%;}
    20% {width: 26%; left: 38%;}
    25% {width: 20%; left: 44%;}
    30% {width: 10%; left: 52%;}
    35% {width: 8%; left: 71%;}
    40% {width: 7%; left: 82%;}
    45% {width: 5%; left: 89%;}
    50% {width: 0%; left: 94%;}
    55% {width: 12%; left: 79%;}
    60% {width: 21%; left: 72%;}
    65% {width: 35%; left: 59%;}
    70% {width: 38%; left: 51%;}
    75% {width: 47%; left: 41%;}
    80% {width: 53%; left: 33%;}
    85% {width: 70%; left: 19%;}
    90% {width: 84%; left: 11%;}
    95% {width: 89%; left: 6%;}
    100%{width: 100%; left: 0%;}
}

Now I can link this to the elements I require as per below:
.animation :nth-child(1) {
    top: 10%;
    animation: slider 3s infinite;
}

if it helps you get a picture of what im doing, the div is styled as below:
.an {
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #09a07a;
    top: 0;
}

This means i have to write one of those repeating code blocks for each child element. I'm not asking you to code the whole thing for me, but just some guidance as to what i should look at when approaching a JS block that will:
Randomly make the element targeted move from one side of the screen to the other, while growing and shrinking in width randomly, this will be applied to each element randomly to save having a code block for each element, but also save writing such a large keyframe.

It would be a lot easier to use Javascript to manipulate the position and width of the elements instead of CSS.  You could maintain an array with each element and its current position in the animation.

For randomness you do need some JS, but using CSS variables you can cut down on code. Currently however you can't have variables defining the 'break points' in a keyframes definition. Just how random do you need things to be?

You only need a few lines of JS to create the .an elements.
The width and left and top and also time of each animation are set in this snippet by setting CSS variables using JS Math.random to make them differ.
Of course you can do more sophisticated things, such as create the keyframes themselves randomly, but I'm not sure a user would notice the subtle differences.


<style>
  @keyframes slider {
    0% {
      width: var(--w0);
      left: var(--l0);
    }
    5% {
      width: var(--w1);
      left: var(--l1);
    }
    10% {
      width: var(--w2);
      left: var(--l2);
    }
    15% {
      width: var(--w3);
      left: var(--l3);
    }
    20% {
      width: var(--w4);
      left: var(--l4);
    }
    25% {
      width: var(--w5);
      left: var(--l5);
    }
    30% {
      width: var(--w6);
      left: var(--l6);
    }
    35% {
      width: var(--w7);
      left: var(--l7);
    }
    40% {
      width: var(--w8);
      left: var(--l8);
    }
    45% {
      width: var(--w9);
      left: var(--l9);
    }
    50% {
      width: var(--w10);
      left: var(--l10);
    }
    55% {
      width: var(--w11);
      left: var(--l11);
    }
    60% {
      width: var(--w12);
      left: var(--l12);
    }
    65% {
      width: var(--w13);
      left: var(--l13);
    }
    70% {
      width: var(--w14);
      left: var(--l14);
    }
    75% {
      width: var(--w15);
      left: var(--l15);
    }
    80% {
      width: var(--w16);
      left: var(--l16);
    }
    85% {
      width: var(--w17);
      left: var(--l17);
    }
    90% {
      width: var(--w18);
      left: var(--l18);
    }
    95% {
      width: var(--w19);
      left: var(--l19);
    }
    100% {
      width: var(--w20);
      left: var(--l20);
    }
  }
  
  .animation {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .an {
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #09a07a;
    top: var(--top);
    animation: slider var(--t) infinite;
  }
</style>
<div class="animation">
</div>
<script>
  let numLines = 5;
  let numSlots = 21;
  let animationEl = document.querySelector('.animation');
  for (let i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
    const line = document.createElement('div');
    line.classList.add('an');
    line.style.setProperty('--top', Math.random() * 100 + '%');
    line.style.setProperty('--t', Math.random() * 5 + 2 + 's');
    for (let j = 0; j < numSlots; j++) {
      line.style.setProperty('--w' + j, Math.random() * 100 + '%');
      line.style.setProperty('--l' + j, Math.random() * 100 + '%');
    }
    animationEl.append(line);
  }
</script>




interesting, so it's better to just create a pre-designed class, but create the divs and assign them on the fly! you basically just wrote it for me, i just need to add margin or top to space them out abit! Thanks for that.

The vertical spacing is random so there will be occasions when two lines are very close or overlap so adding margin or padding to all won’t help. You’d need to either remember where things are and check the following ones aren’t too close, or have numLines regions and assign the lines one to each region.
